# How to open different html file in same window using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have folder which is named as 'Doc', The Doc folder contains some sub folders each folder has '.html' file. I have to open all at time in web breowser using Python code. I opened it but the problem is, the html files is not opening in the same window with new tab. Some times each file is opening  in new window. I dont know what is the exact problem. Here, is the code which I tried

```
import os  
import webbrowser

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Doc"):

    for file in files:

        if file.endswith("index.html"):                    
            webbrowser.open_new_tab(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Answer (score 0):

RTFM (https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html )

> webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
>   Open url in a new page (“tab”) of the default browser, if possible, otherwise equivalent to open_new().

It is a best effort only, presumably depending on the browser too.